# Gradient Descent without derivative

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, backpropagation, gradient-descent

So I’m trying to understand Gradient Descent and I’m confused. If you have a parabola which is of the loss as you change a weight. Instead of taking the derivative at the point of x we are at, why not just easily find the vertex of the parabola?

Comment: Probably, datascience.stackexchange.com is more suitable site for general ML questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can. If your loss function is actually a parabola (or other conveniently convex function), you can. But more likely your loss function is non-convex and super complex, and you don't know a-priori what it is. So we use gradient descent the way we do - we constantly sample. When you see convenient parabolas, that's just a simplified illustration.